# Error when trying to delete widget in KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivymd

I'm trying to write the simplest application in python and kivymd, but I ran into an error.

```
  line 172, in clears
    self.General.ids.BL.remove_widget(self.test)
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'test'
```

Below I will try to write only the main code, for this I will remove unnecessary details so that they do not interfere with perception.

Problem -> The widget cannot be deleted.
After the appearance of MDIconButton from Python code, they need to be removed after a while.
I think that to the MDIconButton elements from the code, you will need to add an id via ids, but so far it is not possible to remove even a widget from the KV markup that already has an id.
I tried to delete the widget via

```
self.General.ids.BL.remove_widget(self.test)
```

But it gives the error that was above.

Ideally, I would like to figure out how to remove widgets from python code, but I would be grateful for any help.
If necessary, I am ready to show the entire code.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivymd.uix import screen
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDIcon, MDLabel

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import random
import os

KV = '''
ScreenManager:

    Screen:
        FitImage:
            source: 'path'




        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'path'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .70}
            user_font_size: '35dp'
            on_release:app.start()

    
    Screen:
        name: 'start_game'
        FitImage:
            source: 'path'

        FloatLayout:
            id : BL
            orientation: 'vertical'

            MDIconButton:
                id:test
                icon: 'path'
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .30, "center_y": .15}
                user_font_size: '35dp'
                on_release:app.Games("one")

            MDIconButton:
                id:two
                icon: 'path'
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .45, "center_y": .2}
                user_font_size: '35dp'
                on_release:app.Games("two")

            MDIconButton:
                id:three
                icon: 'path'
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .60, "center_y": .15}
                user_font_size: '35dp'
                on_release:app.Games("three")

        





'''

        #self.General.ids.BL.remove_widget(self.test)
    

class Game(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.General = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.General

        
    
    def hod_igrok(self, igrok, mix, miy,status=None):
        status = '0'
        if status == 'long':
            igrok = igrok[0].replace(' ','')
        else:
            pass
        print(igrok)

        self.General.ids.BL.add_widget(
            MDIconButton(
                pos_hint={"center_x": mix, "center_y": miy},
                icon=r"path %s.png"%igrok,
                user_font_size= '50dp'

                
            )
        )

  
        return self.General




    def hod_comp(self, comp, c_x, c_y, status=None):

        print(comp)
        status = ' '
        if status == 'long':
            comp = comp[0].replace(' ','')
        else:
            pass


        self.General.ids.BL.add_widget(
            MDIconButton(
                pos_hint={"center_x": c_x, "center_y":c_y},
                icon= r"path c_%s.png"%comp,
                user_font_size='50dp'
                )
            )
       
        return self.General





    def clears(self):
        self.General.ids.BL.remove_widget(self.test)


        
    def Games(self, igrok):
        
        lis = ['kamen','nojnicy', 'bumaga']
        comp= random.choice(lis)



        if comp == "kamen" and igrok == "kamen" or comp == "nojnicy" and igrok == "nojnicy" or comp == "bumaga" and igrok == "bumaga":
            print(comp,'/n',igrok)
            print("Ничья")
            self.hod_igrok(igrok, .45,.50, 'long')
            self.clears()


        elif comp == "kamen" and igrok == "bumaga" or comp == "nojnicy" and igrok == "bumaga" or comp == "bumaga" and igrok == "kamen":
            print(comp,'/n',igrok)
            print("Победил компьютор")
        elif igrok == "bumaga" and comp == "kamen" or igrok == "nojnicy" and comp == "bumaga" or igrok == "kamen" and comp == "nojnicy":
            print(comp,'/n',igrok)
            print("Выиграл игрок")




    def start(self):
        self.root.current= 'start_game'



Game().run()
```

Comment: Please translate the title. [Stack Overflow is an English-only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/4518341). Although if you'd prefer, you could ask on [ru.so] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def remove_the_test_ID_widget(self):
    self.General.ids.BL.remove_widget(self.General.ids.test)
```

In your example, based on the function where or when you need to remove the "test" widget, I put it in the plus sign icon, so when you press it it will remove "test":

```
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivymd.uix import screen
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDIcon, MDLabel

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import random
import os

KV = '''
ScreenManager:

    Screen:
##        FitImage:
##            source: 'path'

        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'pencil'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .70}
            user_font_size: '35dp'
            on_release:app.start()

    
    Screen:
        name: 'start_game'
##        FitImage:
##            source: 'path'

        FloatLayout:
            id : BL
            orientation: 'vertical'

            MDIconButton:
                id:test
                icon: 'pencil'
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .30, "center_y": .15}
                user_font_size: '35dp'
                on_release:app.Games("one")

            MDIconButton:
                id:two
                icon: 'plus'
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .45, "center_y": .2}
                user_font_size: '35dp'
                on_release:app.Games("two"),app.remove_the_test_ID_widget()

            MDIconButton:
                id:three
                icon: 'home'
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .60, "center_y": .15}
                user_font_size: '35dp'
                on_release:app.Games("three")
'''

        #self.General.ids.BL.remove_widget(self.test)
    

class Gamejbsidis(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.General = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.General

    def remove_the_test_ID_widget(self):
        self.General.ids.BL.remove_widget(self.General.ids.test)
    
    def hod_igrok(self, igrok, mix, miy,status=None):
        status = '0'
        if status == 'long':
            igrok = igrok[0].replace(' ','')
        else:
            pass
        print(igrok)

        self.General.ids.BL.add_widget(
            MDIconButton(
                pos_hint={"center_x": mix, "center_y": miy},
                icon=r"path %s.png"%igrok,
                user_font_size= '50dp'

                
            )
        )

        return self.General




    def hod_comp(self, comp, c_x, c_y, status=None):

        print(comp)
        status = ' '
        if status == 'long':
            comp = comp[0].replace(' ','')
        else:
            pass


        self.General.ids.BL.add_widget(
            MDIconButton(
                pos_hint={"center_x": c_x, "center_y":c_y},
                icon= r"path c_%s.png"%comp,
                user_font_size='50dp'
                )
            )
       
        return self.General





    def clears(self):
        self.General.ids.BL.remove_widget(self.test)


        
    def Games(self, igrok):
        
        lis = ['kamen','nojnicy', 'bumaga']
        comp= random.choice(lis)



        if comp == "kamen" and igrok == "kamen" or comp == "nojnicy" and igrok == "nojnicy" or comp == "bumaga" and igrok == "bumaga":
            print(comp,'/n',igrok)
            print("Ничья")
            self.hod_igrok(igrok, .45,.50, 'long')
            self.clears()


        elif comp == "kamen" and igrok == "bumaga" or comp == "nojnicy" and igrok == "bumaga" or comp == "bumaga" and igrok == "kamen":
            print(comp,'/n',igrok)
            print("Победил компьютор")
        elif igrok == "bumaga" and comp == "kamen" or igrok == "nojnicy" and comp == "bumaga" or igrok == "kamen" and comp == "nojnicy":
            print(comp,'/n',igrok)
            print("Выиграл игрок")




    def start(self):
        self.root.current= 'start_game'



Gamejbsidis().run()
```

Picture:
[image]